# get current url in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` and loading an `NSURL`  there are 4 links in that page when I click a link this method is called. which is fine

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{ 
}
```

after moving to next page my `UINavigationBar` shows a `back button`

```
 -(void)backButtonClicked
{
if ( myWebView.loading) 
{
    [myWebView goBack];
       } 
}
```

which takes me back to the main page, but if I again click the same link no delegate method is called. why is that? I need to get the current url every time I click a link.

Comment: Could you give the URL that you are opening in `webview` so that I can test

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in delegate...

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    NSLog(@"Webview url: %@",webView.request.URL.absoluteString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all the opened URLs in an array and when back button check if the tapped link is same as of stored link in array on last object then reload the web view.